# Setting values and handling concurrency in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.1 and my service update method looks like so

```
public async override Task<int> UpdateAsync(Module updated)
{
    var entity = await _context.Modules
        .Where(e => e.Id == updated.Id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // update existing values
    _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);

    // do not update
    _context.SetModified(entity, "AddOnlyProperty", false);

    return await base.UpdateAsync(entity);
}
```

My base UpdateAsync looks like so

```
public async virtual Task<int> UpdateAsync(T updated)
{
    var results = await ValidateAsync(updated);

    if (!results.IsValid)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(results.Errors);
    }

    if (_context.GetState(updated) == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(updated);
        _context.SetState(updated, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    // we do not want the createdDate to change when an update is being done
    _context.SetModified(updated, "CreatedDate", false);
    _context.SetModified(updated, "CreatedByUserId", false);

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This method is very simple, it copies the changes from updated into the entity, that way EF will only apply the changes needed when it creates the SQL.

My problem is that concurrency doesnt seem to be working, i would expect a DbConcurrencyException to be thrown?

Here is my basic Module object

```
public class Module : EntityBase, IEntityVersion, IEntityDelete
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured RowVersion as a rowVersion field in my Module.config file, like so

```
this.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
    .IsRowVersion();
```

Now when i perform an update with an old rowVersion value, the update seems to still take place?  Have i missed a configuration setting or am i doing this wrong?

Should an exception be thrown, or should i be checking if the rowVersion values match myself?

Answer (score 2):

You retrieve the record.

You then modify the record.

Someone else modifies the record too, and saves the change.

You retrieve the record again, and update the values to match your desired values.

You save your changes.

The problem here is the "You retrieve the record again" step. Because you do this *after* the other person saved the changes, you get the new row version value already. This is the step you need to skip.

One way of handling it is using one `Context` throughout the process, and leaving the entity-to-be-modified attached to the context. Entity Framework will be able to keep track of the original values.

Another way of handling it is keeping track of the original values yourself. When you want to save the changes, create a detached entity, set the properties to the original values, attach it to the context, and then set the properties to the modified values.

---

Actually, thinking about it some more, instead of using on EF's concurrency handling, you should be able to trivially code your own here:

```
var entity = await _context.Modules
    .Where(e => e.Id == updated.Id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
if (entity == null) {
  ... // throw exception about record not existing in the database
}
if (BitConverter.ToInt64(entity.RowVersion, 0) != BitConverter.ToInt64(updated.RowVersion, 0)) {
  ... // throw exception about record having been updated in the database
}
... // your existing code to update the entity can go here
```

Comment: But if i retrieve the entity and overwrite it's values surely the row version would be overwritten and therefore it should use this value to check if it's the latest version? Or are u saying because I retrieved it from the db, entity framework thinks it should be the latest version anyway and ignores it?

Comment: Can u give me an example of how to keep track of changes myself? Only doing it this way so properties that are changed are modified

Comment: @user2736022 Entity Framework uses change tracking, and keeps the old and the new values for all properties (which will be equal if the entity is unchanged). It uses the old value of the row version for concurrency checks, and ignores any new value you try to give it. In your case, the value that EF sees as the old value isn't actually the old value you want to use for your concurrency check.

Comment: @user2736022 That could be as simple as `public async override Task<int> UpdateAsync(Module original, Module updated)`, attaching `original` or a clone of `original`, and updating its properties to `updated`.

Comment: If you need to retrieve the record before saving, eg. in the case of ASP.Net, the most simple examples I've seen do this in a Save function: Get the current version of the record from the db, update the values to change, overwrite the original rowversion value (`ctx.Entry(objToUpdate).OriginalValues["rowversion"] = Rowversion;`), then save. Entity Framework attempts to save the record with the matching ID and rowversion that was used when the user originally loaded the record. If the db record has changed, exception occurs. This way you only have to keep track of the original rowversion value.

Answer (score 2):

You must add this to force ef to add condition for checking RowVersion on update.

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).OriginalValues["RowVersion "] = yourCurrentRowVersion;
```